# Using entangled particles to transfer energy or a force?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

My question is a two part question:

1. When two particles that have mass are entangled (e.g. two electrons) are their Higgs field(s)/mass also entangled?
2. If mass is an entanglable property of particles would it be possible to transmit force/energy between two entangled particles in the following method?  Method: Take two entangled particles and place them in two separate circular particle accelerators A and B.  The particle in accelerator A is accelerated up to relativistic speeds such that the mass in the particle is increased by the velocity. Then the particle in accelerator A's velocity is pulsed between two speeds such that the particle's mass varies between two levels.  The particle in accelerator B is synchronized with the change in mass of the particle in accelerator A (and particle B because their mass is entangled) such that the particle reaches its maximum mass at one point/side of the accelerator and its minimum mass at the opposite side of the accelerator. In this scenario wouldn't the two accelerators have a net force on each other regardless of distance between them?

Comment: "The mass of  the particle is increased by the velocity".   Putting aside a bunch of other troublesome issues, are you suggesting that this particle *has* a well-defined mass?  If so, the masses are  no longer entangled, are they?

Comment: By "The mass of the particle[s] is increased by the velocity" i'm intending to say that the total energy of the two entangled particles is increase by accelerating one of the particles. 
 See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity

Comment: I'm not sure accelerating one of two particle of two particles with entangled mass, an unknown amount, would necessarily collapse the wave function, breaking entanglement.  If it did it would not be possible to separate mass entangled particles in the first place which would answer to part one of my question.